# Como fazer para esconder e habilitar uma linha de uma table?

Tags: javascript, html

Não sei o que acontece, mas quando inicio a tela com o display block no id impar, tudo ok
porém quando desabilito, e habilito novamente, os campos das colunas aparecem tudo na
primeira coluna

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

thead tr {
  background-color: ActiveCaption;
  color: CaptionText;
}

th,
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#impar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col0">COLUNA 1</th>
      <th class="col1">COLUNA 2</th>
      <th class="col2">COLUNA 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="par" onclick="Mudarestado('impar')">
      <td class="col0">CAMPO DA COLUNA 1</td>
      <td class="col1">CAMPO DA COLUNA 2</td>
      <td class="col2">CAMPO DA COLUNA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="impar">
      <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 1</td>
      <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 2</td>
      <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o valor de display do elemento  não é block, mas sim table-row.

Esta ajuste na função Mudarestado() resolve o problema:

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'table-row';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col0">COLUNA 1</th>
        <th class="col1">COLUNA 2</th>
        <th class="col2">COLUNA 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="par" onclick="Mudarestado('impar')">
        <td class="col0">CAMPO DA COLUNA 1</td>
        <td class="col1">CAMPO DA COLUNA 2</td>
        <td class="col2">CAMPO DA COLUNA 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="impar" style="display: none;">
        <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 1</td>
        <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 2</td>
        <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Edit:** removi o CSS, e adicionei o `display: none` de forma inline na linha #impar, pois estava causando um problema no primeiro clique, já que o `element.style.display` somente lê estilos inline.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score -1):

Olá, no lugar do 'block', coloca o 'table-row'. Espero ter ajudado
document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'table-row';

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'table-row';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

thead tr {
  background-color: ActiveCaption;
  color: CaptionText;
}

th,
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#impar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col0">COLUNA 1</th>
      <th class="col1">COLUNA 2</th>
      <th class="col2">COLUNA 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="par" onclick="Mudarestado('impar')">
      <td class="col0">CAMPO DA COLUNA 1</td>
      <td class="col1">CAMPO DA COLUNA 2</td>
      <td class="col2">CAMPO DA COLUNA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="impar">
      <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 1</td>
      <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 2</td>
      <td>CAMPO OBSERVACAO DA COLUNA 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Agora sim!!
Muito obrigado, era isso que tava faltando